# Xamarin Forms Dependency Service definition issue

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm developing and app with Xamarin and I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) in order to implement and interface for Xamarin Forms for UWP.

So I wrote in PCL this interface:

```
namespace MyApp {
public interface ISimplePdfLoader {

    void OpenLocal(string uri);

    void Load(object pdfDoc);
  }
}
```

and in MyApp.UWP I created a class:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SimplePdfLoader))]
namespace MyApp.UWP {
public class SimplePdfLoader : ISimplePdfLoader {

    public async void OpenLocal(string uri) {
        ...

        Load(doc);
    }

    public async void Load(object pdfObj) {
        ...
        }
    }
}
}
```

But it continues to show the `error CS7036 No arguments matching the mandatory formal parameter 'loadHintArgument' of 'DependencyAttribute.DependencyAttribute (string, LoadHint)'` were specified  MyApp.UWP   C:\Users...\workspace\my-app\MyApp\MyApp.UWP\SimplePdfLoader.cs    19
and I can not compile the project.

**edit:** The error is show underlying the line `[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SimplePdfLoader))]`

Comment: Did you manually register each dependency service in your App.xaml.cs file? Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction#universal-windows-platform-net-native-compilation

Comment: @JesseK I tried but it tells "In the App.xaml.cs file, manually register each dependency service defined in the UWP project" but I have a App.xaml.cs file both in MyApp and in MyApp.UWP, where should I put the registration?

Comment: I believe it should be the one in your UWP project.

Comment: @JesseK It says to add this line: Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, assembliesToInclude); but I don't know what is assembliesToInclude or the e variable

Comment: Can you try it without that line and only the line: `Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Register<SimplePdfLoader>();`

Comment: @JesseK same error, I edited the question with one more detail.

Comment: You probably have a using statement referring to the Dependency class in System.Runtime.CompilerServices, not in Xamarin.Forms

Comment: Yes @Benl, i think that should be fixed with my suggestion in the answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Remove the below line from top usings section

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
```

and add the below

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SimplePdfLoader))]` into `[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency()]`. Can you see what parameters you can provide to that Dependency object? I think it should be this `[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(SimplePdfLoader))]`